# Storing a reference variable (Reference to Reference)

Tags: c#, reference

In C++ i would use Type ** var to do this.  How is this accomplished in C#?  Here is an example of what is occurring.  This is pretty rough pseudo-code...

```
Class Main{
    class DataObj {...};

    class Param
    {
        public DataObj obj;
        public CBFunc f;

    }

    // Start a load, DataObj o should be set once the load is complete
    void Load(string fn, DataObj o, CBFunc func)
    {
        Param p = new Param();
        p.obj = o;
        p.f = func;

        // will call the CBFunc when done...
        LoadWithCB(fn, CBFunc, p);
    }

    void CBFunc(Param p, DataObject o)
    {
        // DataObj o is what was loaded.  p.obj is set to o...
        p.obj = o;
        p.f();
    }


    DataObj A;

    void Init()
    {
        Load("...",A, MyCBFunc);
    }

    void MyCBFunc()
    {
        //A now is filled out
        A.whatever();
    }
 }
```

***Please note that this code DOES NOT work and the typing of vars is incorrect... I just don't know what the types should be to accomplish this...***

So what is desired is having a DataObj A, call Init which loads and will at some point later call the function MyCBFunc.  At this point A should be filled out.  In C++ I would pass around a **var which then could be de-referenced and set correctly filling out the variable correctly.

So is there a way to pass A into Load, and what is the type that should be on the signature as well and the declaration of DataObj obj in Param that would allow this to be passed as a reference?

This is in managed C#.

Comment: What is your objective (other than the mechanics you're describing)?  What is it that you're trying to accomplish?  You're hitting us with a solution to some problem, and asking us how to make it work; hit us with the actual problem you're trying to solve, and we'll show you how to do *that* in C#.  Not all C++ thinking is going to map directly to C#.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Are you talking about the `ref` keyword?

Comment: You'd use the `ref` keyword here, but thats not good practice. Why don't you just return the value of `o` and set it that way? Or pass in a closure that modifies the value. There are a lot of alternate solutions.

Comment: It seems like you also want to use function pointers, so I'd suggest you look up the Func<>, Action<>, and Predicate<> delegates.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Im sorry if it wasn't clear, what I am wondering is, if C# has a syntax for storing pointers to pointers, or better worded in C# a reference to a reference.    The ref keyword works if you don't have several levels of threading occurring.  When you have to wait for something to happen, whether that be a file load or a WWW request to return, the program can't wait, but when it returns I need that variable to be set, but passing that variable to different levels doesn't work, EXCEPT for the accepted answer's case.  Just trying to map my C++ knowledge onto C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store a reference variable by (you'll never guess this).... using a class member variable of reference type.

```
class RefHolder<T>
{
    public T ptr;
}
```

Now you can use multiple indirection all day long:

```
RefHolder<RefHolder<RefHolder<string>>>
```

If you pass a `RefHolder<string>` to another component, you can change it's `ptr` value later, and the component can then access your new `string`.

Comment: Hmmm... your solution is much more elegant than mine... I actually just declared a very specific ptr.  But back to the actual question, other than this "hack", C# doesn't provide any type/casting to do this?

Comment: I'm not aware of a framework-provided strong reference class, although an array of size 1 can do the same if you don't want a custom type.

Comment: Other strategies include passing a Func<T> containing a lambda that accesses a value (useful for properties) or using actual pointers within an unsafe{}. This answer is probably a better idea though.

Comment: @Alex: In many cases two `Func` objects would be needed (one for read, one for write), and the lambda is just going to create a helper class to hold the variable anyway.  But it is more powerful (for example, compatible with property setter and getter as you mentioned).

Comment: @BenVoigt: You are totally correct, though imo having it create the helper class is better than doing it yourself.